# How can I find a special character like '!' or '?' in an objects array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, foreach, javascript-objects

I wanted to find the usernames with '!' and '?' in an objects array and store them in a new array.

The objects array is as follows.

```
const array = [
  {
    username: "john!",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy?",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },

];
```

I tried the `test()` method with `forEach` looping, but I couldn't get the preferred output. How can I do it? Can I use `map()` instead of `forEach` to iterate through objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific to your use case this is how you would get all the usernames that contain those characters.

`Array.filter` creates a new array so you dont have to mutate the original one to get the values you want.

```js
array.filter(obj => obj.username.includes("!") || obj.username.includes("?"))
```

Comment: Only use snippets for working examples with output. Otherwise, use code blocks instead. Also, when you have multiple string tests, it is usually cleaner to use a regular expression. In this case, `/\?|!/` works fine. Lastly, the array should include usernames, not entire objects.

Comment: I like this shorthand way of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Here is a simple single-line solution to your problem:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    username: "john!",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy?",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },

]

let newArr = []

arr.forEach(({username}) => username.match(/[?|!]/g) ? newArr.push(username) : null)

console.log(newArr)
```

### How it works

First, we loop through all of the elements in the array using:

```js
arr.forEach(({username}) => ...)
```

Then we check to see if the `username` contains a '!' or '?' using a regular expression (regex):

```js
username.match(/[?|!]/g)
```

If it does contain a '?' or '!' then push the username to a new array:

```js
newArr.push(username)
```

If the username does not match, return `null`.

Comment: OP said he wanted the usernames only. Also, he said he wanted usernames WITH ? and !, not without.

Comment: @ElectricShadow Sorry didn't realise just updated it, still got it to be one line tho 

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
  {
    username: "john!",
    team: "red",
    score: 5,
    items: ["ball", "book", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    team: "blue",
    score: 10,
    items: ["tape", "backpack", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "susy?",
    team: "red",
    score: 55,
    items: ["ball", "eraser", "pen"]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    team: "green",
    score: 1,
    items: ["book", "pen"]
  },
];

const usernames = array
  .filter(({ username }) => /\?|!/.test(username))
  .map(({ username }) => username);

console.log(usernames);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the job.

```
const names = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (/[!?]$/.test(item.username)) {
    acc.push(item.username);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: OP never specified that the ? or ! had to be the last character.

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.prototype.filter() in order to filter out the objects whose username includes ! or ?  or other characters which you want to check for into a new array.

```js
 const array = [
      {
        username: 'john!',
        team: 'red',
        score: 5,
        items: ['ball', 'book', 'pen'],
      },
      {
        username: 'becky',
        team: 'blue',
        score: 10,
        items: ['tape', 'backpack', 'pen'],
      },
      {
        username: 'susy?',
        team: 'red',
        score: 55,
        items: ['ball', 'eraser', 'pen'],
      },
      {
        username: 'tyson',
        team: 'green',
        score: 1,
        items: ['book', 'pen'],
      },
    ];
    
    const filteredArray = array.filter(object => {
//You need to add your characters in the below condition to check for them I have //added for ! & ? for now
      return object.username.includes('!') || object.username.includes('?'); 
    });
    console.log(filteredArray);

//To get just the usernames
filteredArray.forEach(object => console.log(object.username));
```

Comment: This also worked. Thanks! I wanted to get the usernames only.